# How do I convert dynamic class to json or java file in Frida

Tags: java, android, dynamic-class-loaders, frida

is there any solution for dynamic classes convert to json or java file? I can load and see their methods arguments with frida but I need what  is happening inside it and what type of dynamic class, bytecode?

Comment: Java byte/dex code that is executed at run-time has to be loaded first. I would assume that the change to get access to the byte code is the highest when hooking the Android [ClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader) implementations, especially those methods that actually load the class into memory e.g. form a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this guy I found a solution. Maybe, in future, if someone will need
[dump dex dynamic from loaded class](https://github.com/GuoQiang1993/Frida-Apk-Unpack/blob/master/dexDump.js)